# PHP, dynamically show source into other div in same page after php is submitted

Tags: javascript, php, html, generator, view-source

I am here to ask You the best way of creating a 'generator'.

What have i done so far:
Php file with retrieving posted data,

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- 33 KB -->

<!-- fotorama.css & fotorama.js. -->
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fotorama/4.6.2/fotorama.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- 3 KB -->
<script>
  fotoramaDefaults = {
    width: 700,
    maxwidth: '100%',
    ratio: 16/9,
    allowfullscreen: true,
    nav: 'thumbs'

  }
</script>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fotorama/4.6.2/fotorama.js"></script> <!-- 16 KB -->
</head>
<body>
<?php 
  switch($_POST['amountofimages']){
case '1':
echo '<div class="fotorama" data-nav="thumbs" data-autoplay="1700">';
echo '<img src="' . $_POST['hrefimg1'] . '">';
echo '</div>';
break;
case '2':

echo '<div class="fotorama" data-nav="thumbs" data-autoplay="1700">';
echo '<img src="' . $_POST['hrefimg1'] . '">';
echo '<img src="' . $_POST['hrefimg2'] . '">';
echo '</div>';
break;
case '3':

echo '<div class="fotorama" data-nav="thumbs" data-autoplay="1700">';
echo '<img src="' . $_POST['hrefimg1'] . '">';
echo '<img src="' . $_POST['hrefimg2'] . '">';
echo '<img src="' . $_POST['hrefimg3'] . '">';
echo '</div>';
break;
default:
echo "Could not load images";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

After sumbiting post.html with field required to generate html from php above.
Everything goes fine but I need to be able view actual generated source after submition. Not real page view.

I have tried inserting this javascript code:

```
<a class="button" onClick='window.location="view-source:" + window.location.href'>View Source</a>
```

But it shows me complete source of page including viewsource code.
How can i hide the last part of it?
Or even better do it on one page as http://jsfiddle.net/ do.
But only with
Fields to fill, checkboxes i can do it and post to same page so it will show it fine but i have problem with showing actual source of generated page into same page into another DIV.

Any suggestions?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you need to process the data with PHP? I mean - do you store `$_POST` values somewhere?

Comment: Yes i do have other php file, after user is logged in he is redirected to generator html page with fields to be filled and submitted or cookie stored for later use.

Comment: Do I well understand - you want to print all the code (with body, head, scripts) as text, in some DIV? And you post the data to the same page you are? (I would make separate PHP page to retrieve the `$_POST` data and send it back to initial page using Ajax)

Comment: @phillip100 yes i do wish to do that, i could, echo all code separate but it takes a lot longer and post data to _self, to show generated content in single page, but since i have few templates i would have to phase all of them in main one file, i have login based system before you are able to post all data, actually instead of that i have found other way, once we are posting to other php file, at end of it i have placed curl to fetch whole generated page, into a file. Then if user goes back to home page div popes up if file is generated with user password protected href to download. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since your using jQuery you can take advantage of [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to escape html for you.

```
var $pre = $('<pre/>');
var bodyHTML = $('body').html();
$pre.text(bodyHTML);
$('body').append($pre);
```

Comment: It working just exactly as i used, view-source method, and it would be the answer but it shows me this: code on bottom of this page, but i will try to play around with string.replace(searchvalue,newvalue), to get rid of not needed scripts. So i can use it in different div instead. I think that is the only way i can make it happen. But thanks anyways. I will keep trying.